# How to solve Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> in nested map?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm not finding a way to solve this error in my nested map function , everything that I try ends up in a sintax error.

My code:

```
    {import codes....}
    const FormScreen = ({route}) => {
     const [FieldForm, setFieldForm] = useState([]);
     const [TypeForm, setTypeForm] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
      if (FieldForm.length > 0) {   
        return;
      } else {
        setFieldForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey).message);
        setTypeForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey).tipo);
        console.log('SETINGGG',FieldForm,TypeForm);
      }
    },[FieldForm,TypeForm]);
return (<View>             
             {FieldForm.length > 0 ? (
                    FieldForm.map((item) => (
                      <>          
                        <Text>{`${JSON.stringify(item)}`}</Text>
                        <>
                        {TypeForm.map((type) => (  
                          <Text>{`${JSON.stringify(type)}`}</Text>
                        ))}
                        </>
                      </>
                    ))
                  ) : (
                    <Text key={uuid.v4()}> Loading ...</Text>
                  )}
            </View>
```

I tried to remove these  components but it not worked, how can I make it work ?

Comment: What is the type of `item` and `type`?

Comment: Did you try removing the elements until the error is resolved?

Comment: @MaartenDev they are a object(which is varialble), example of `console.log(type,item)` is `{"message": ["abs", "test"],"tipo": [ "Date","Text"]}`

Comment: Wait so how do you expect React native to display that object? It doesn't known how to render those objects?

Comment: @MaartenDev I tried to remove some of these `<>` and these `<Text>` , but all of my tries ends up in a sintax error

Comment: @MaartenDev Infact when it was only my Field map it was rendering, but when I tried to nest it , it started this error

Comment: You can only use string values within a `<Text />` tag. You have to access properties within the `item` and `type` object to show the values.

Comment: @MaartenDev I tried to remove the Text tag just now and the error still the same, and I also Tried to use like `<Text value='item'>`, but it also not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 {TypeForm.map((type) => (  
    <Text>{`${JSON.stringify(type)}`}</Text>
 ))}; // remove this ; (dot and comma)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a template string like `` {`${type}`} ``

I would think you're going to end up with `[Object]` as your text body, but that's a good starting point to start getting the values that you want.

Edit: The `` ` `` are called backticks and they're used for creating `template strings` or `string literals`.  Instead of using double quotes to represent a string value, we use these. Template strings are able to have nested object values inside of them and print their string representation. If it's just a JSON object that you're trying to print in the template string, you're going to wind up printing `[Object]`. That's going to tell you that you're not actually printing the value of the object that you want, and you're probably after `type.value`, but to find the key/value of the object that you may be looking for, you could try something like `` <Text>{`${JSON.stringify(type)}`}</Text> ``.

Comment: I didn't understood how this `{${type}}` works, could you explain me ? @Jon

Comment: Sure! Check my edit and let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I tried to change all my `<Text>` tags to the ones that you sugested, thanks for that , but it still giving me same error @Jon

Comment: I noticed `{...}` at the top of your code block as well, that would cause a syntax error as that's a spread operator and you're not actually spreading anything.

Comment: I changed and posted the whole code this `{...}` I used to not show what could be an "useless" information @Jon

Comment: Gotcha - could you try wrapping the `View` in a return like `return (<View>{... stuff}</View>)` ?

Comment: I tried to use this but the error still @Jon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239713/discussion-between-jon-and-guilherme-cavenaghi).